# Событие от клиентской валидации в Yii2

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Есть форма.

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['myAction'],
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
]);
```

Сделал отправку при submit`е через ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    method: form.attr('method')
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data == "success") {
        //все ок, обрабатываем
    } else {
        //перебираем все ошибки и показываем их в форме
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $("#"+key).after("<div class=\"help-block\">"+val+"</div>");   
            $("#"+key).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        });
    }
});
```

Но клиентская валидация тоже пишет в форму сообщение об ошибке. И получается вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем случае клиентская валидацию проходит после моего запроса и проверить на наличие ошибки от клиента не получается.

Хотелось бы сначала смотреть на клиента, если ошибки нет, то слать запрос.

Как это сделать? Как отловить событие клиентской валидации? Или может как-то можно запустить ее вручную?

Comment: Зачем вы делаете свои проверки и при этом используете встроенные проверки? Зачем костылить там, где это не нужно? Все проверки Вы прописываете в rules вашей модели

Comment: Мне нужно проверять данные при submit`е через ajax. Такая возможность есть встроенная в Yii2 ?

Comment: Все проверки, конечно же, прописаны в rules, в модели

Comment: Клиентская валидация подразумевает проверку формы до ее отправки, вы же сначала отправляете данные, а потом проверяете и добавляете ошибки. То есть полностью дублируете функционал activeform. То есть саму $.ajax ... вы должны обернуть в условие. И если это условие выполнено, то запрос отправится. Однако вам нужно включить EnableClientScript

Answer (score -2):

Разобрался! Делается это так:

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['myAction'],
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
]);
```

Надо было добавить '`validateOnSubmit' => true`

Answer (score -3):

Если у Вас стоит параметр **'enableClientValidation' => true,** то Вам незачем делать свои проверки так как в Yii2 есть собственный валидатор, а правила для него пишутся в моделе, если Вам нужно больше гибкости то читайте про [ActiveField](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html) и такие валидаторы как when и whenClient. И вот ещё есть интересная [вещь](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/).